# Unresolved External Symbol Error while compiling dblognoconn.obj

Tags: c, db2

I am working with DB2 LUW latest version. I Have to read the logs through dblognoconn.sqc file.

I followed the steps from this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/t0020937.html)

Precompiled Using -> **"bldapp dblognoconn"**
I got .c file and .bnd file

I created obj file using this command -> **cl -Zi -Od -c -W2 -DWIN32 dblognoconn.c**

.obj is created successfully with following warnings,

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\samples\c\utilrecov.c(432): note: consider using '%X' in the format string
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\samples\c\utilrecov.c(432): note: consider using '%I32X' in the format string
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\samples\c\utilrecov.c(433): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%04llX' requires an argument of type 'unsigned __int64', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\samples\c\utilrecov.c(433): note: consider using '%X' in the format string
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\samples\c\utilrecov.c(433): note: consider using '%I32X' in the format string
dblognoconn.sqc(241): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'void *' to 'int'
dblognoconn.sqc(242): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'void *' to 'int'
dblognoconn.sqc(244): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'void *' to 'int'
```

Then I used this command to create .exe file -> **link -debug -out:log.exe dblognoconn.obj**

This command gives output like this

```
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlacall referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlastop referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlastrt referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqledrpd_api referenced in function DbDrop
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlecrea_api referenced in function DbCreate
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2CfgSet referenced in function DbLogRetainValueRestore
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2CfgGet referenced in function ServerWorkingPathGet
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2Prune referenced in function DbRecoveryHistoryFilePrune
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2Backup referenced in function DbBackup
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2ArchiveLog referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2ReadLogNoConnInit referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2ReadLogNoConn referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db2ReadLogNoConnTerm referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SqlInfoPrint referenced in function ServerWorkingPathGet
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CmdLineArgsCheck3 referenced in function main
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol InstanceAttach referenced in function main
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol InstanceDetach referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol DbConn referenced in function DbRecoveryHistoryFilePrune
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol DbDisconn referenced in function DbRecoveryHistoryFilePrune
dblognoconn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TransRollback referenced in function DbReadLogRecordsNoConn
log.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved externals
```

dblognoconn.c file after the precompilation of dblognoconn.sqc file

```
static char sqla_program_id[292] = 
{
 '\xac','\x0','\x41','\x45','\x41','\x56','\x41','\x49','\x72','\x41','\x6f','\x79','\x4e','\x51','\x4a','\x6a','\x30','\x31','\x31','\x31',
 '\x31','\x20','\x32','\x20','\x20','\x20','\x20','\x20','\x20','\x20','\x20','\x20','\xd','\x0','\x41','\x44','\x4d','\x49','\x4e','\x49',
 '\x53','\x54','\x52','\x41','\x54','\x4f','\x52','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x8','\x0','\x44','\x42','\x4c','\x4f','\x47','\x4e','\x4f','\x43','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0',
 '\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0','\x0'
};

#include "sqladef.h"

static struct sqla_runtime_info sqla_rtinfo = 
{{'S','Q','L','A','R','T','I','N'}, sizeof(wchar_t), 0, {' ',' ',' ',' '}};


static const short sqlIsLiteral   = SQL_IS_LITERAL;
static const short sqlIsInputHvar = SQL_IS_INPUT_HVAR;


#line 1 "dblognoconn.sqc"
/****************************************************************************
** (c) Copyright IBM Corp. 2007 All rights reserved.
** 
** The following sample of source code ("Sample") is owned by International 
** Business Machines Corporation or one of its subsidiaries ("IBM") and is 
** copyrighted and licensed, not sold. You may use, copy, modify, and 
** distribute the Sample in any form without payment to IBM, for the purpose of 
** assisting you in the development of your applications.
** 
** The Sample code is provided to you on an "AS IS" basis, without warranty of 
** any kind. IBM HEREBY EXPRESSLY DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES, EITHER EXPRESS OR 
** IMPLIED, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF 
** MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. Some jurisdictions do 
** not allow for the exclusion or limitation of implied warranties, so the above 
** limitations or exclusions may not apply to you. IBM shall not be liable for 
** any damages you suffer as a result of using, copying, modifying or 
** distributing the Sample, even if IBM has been advised of the possibility of 
** such damages.
*****************************************************************************
**
** SOURCE FILE NAME: dblognoconn.sqc
**
** SAMPLE: How to read the database logs with no database connection
**
** Archive logging needs to be enabled to read database logs when there is 
** no connection to the database. The database logs are archived and read 
** from the archive location.
**
** PREREQUISITES : Update the db cfg parameter to enable archive logging :
**    
**    db2 UPDATE DB CFG FOR SAMPLE USING LOGARCHMETH1 DISK:<archive log path>
**         <archive log path> : path with write permission where the 
**                              database logs can be archived
**    db2 TERMINATE 
**    db2 BACKUP DB SAMPLE
**
** Note : You must be disconnected from the sample database to run this 
**        program. To ensure you are, enter 'db2 CONNECT RESET' on the
**        command line prior to running the sample.
**
** EXECUTION : dblognoconn <db name> <nodename> <username> <pswd>
**
** Note : Perform 'db2 RESET DB CFG FOR SAMPLE' after running the sample
**
** DB2 APIs USED:
**         db2CfgGet -- Get db configuration parameters
**         db2ArchiveLog  -- Archive the active log files
**         db2ReadLogNoConn -- Read the database logs without a db connection 
**         db2ReadLogNoConnInit -- Initialize reading the database logs 
**                                 without a db connection 
**         db2ReadLogNoConnTerm -- Terminate reading the database logs 
**                                 without a db connection 
**
** OUTPUT FILE: dblognoconn.out (available in the online documentation)
*****************************************************************************
**
** For detailed information about database backup and database recovery, see
** the Data Recovery and High Availability Guide and Reference. This manual
** will help you to determine which database and table space recovery methods
** are best suited to your business environment.
**
** For more information on the sample programs, see the README file.
**
** For information on developing C applications, see the Application
** Development Guide.
**
** For information on using SQL statements, see the SQL Reference.
**
** For information on DB2 APIs, see the Administrative API Reference.
**
** For the latest information on programming, building, and running DB2
** applications, visit the DB2 application development website:
**     http://www.software.ibm.com/data/db2/udb/ad
****************************************************************************/
#include "utilrecov.c"
#include "utilemb.h"

/* local function prototypes */
int DbReadLogRecordsNoConn(char *, char *, char *, char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rc = 0;
  char nodeName[SQL_INSTNAME_SZ + 1] = { 0 };
  char serverWorkingPath[SQL_PATH_SZ + 1] = { 0 };
  char dbAlias[SQL_ALIAS_SZ + 1] = { 0 };
  char user[USERID_SZ + 1] = { 0 };
  char pswd[PSWD_SZ + 1] = { 0 };

  /* check the command line arguments */
  rc = CmdLineArgsCheck3(argc, argv, dbAlias, nodeName, user, pswd);
  CHECKRC(rc, "CmdLineArgsCheck3");

  printf("\nTHIS SAMPLE SHOWS HOW TO READ DATABASE LOGS ASYNCHRONOUSLY\n");
  printf("WITH NO DATABASE CONNECTION.\n");

  /* attach to a local or remote instance */
  rc = InstanceAttach(nodeName, user, pswd);
  CHECKRC(rc, "Instance Attach");

  /* get the server working path */
  rc = ServerWorkingPathGet(dbAlias, serverWorkingPath);
  CHECKRC(rc, "ServerWorkingPathGet");

  /* call the routine to prune the history files */
  rc = DbRecoveryHistoryFilePrune(dbAlias, user, pswd);
  CHECKRC(rc, "DbRecoveryHistoryFilePrune");

  /* call the routine to read the log records for no db connection */
  rc = DbReadLogRecordsNoConn(dbAlias, nodeName, user, pswd, serverWorkingPath);
  CHECKRC(rc, "DbReadLogRecordsNoConn");

  return 0;
} /* end main */

int DbReadLogRecordsNoConn(char dbAlias[],
                           char nodeName[],
                           char user[],
                           char pswd[],
                           char serverWorkingPath[])
{
  int rc = 0;
  struct sqlca sqlca = { 0 };
  char logPath[SQL_PATH_SZ + 1] = { 0 };
  db2CfgParam cfgParameters[1] = { 0 };
  db2Cfg cfgStruct = { 0 };
  char nodeNum[] = "NODE0000\0";
  db2Uint32 readLogMemSize = 0;
  char *readLogMemory = NULL;
  struct db2ArchiveLogStruct archiveLogInput = { 0 };
  struct db2ReadLogNoConnInitStruct readLogInit = { 0 };
  struct db2ReadLogNoConnInfoStruct readLogInfo = { 0 };
  struct db2ReadLogNoConnStruct readLogInput = { 0 };
  db2LSN startLSN;
  db2LSN endLSN;
  char *logBuffer = NULL;
  db2Uint32 logBufferSize = 0;
  struct db2ReadLogNoConnTermStruct readLogTerm = { 0 };

  printf("\n*********************************\n");
  printf("*** NO DB CONNECTION READ LOG ***\n");
  printf("*********************************\n");
  printf("\nUSE THE DB2 APIs:\n");
  printf("  db2ArchiveLog  -- Archive the active log files\n");
  printf("  db2ReadLogNoConnInit -- Initialize reading the database ");
  printf("logs without a db connection\n");
  printf("  db2ReadLogNoConn -- Read the database logs without a db connection\n");
  printf("  db2ReadLogNoConnTerm -- Terminate reading the database logs ");
  printf("without a db connection\n");
  printf("TO READ LOG RECORDS FROM THE ARCHIVED LOG DIRECTORY.\n");

  /* Determine the logpath to read log files from */
  cfgParameters[0].flags = 0;
  cfgParameters[0].token = SQLF_DBTN_LOGARCHMETH1;
  cfgParameters[0].ptrvalue =
    (char *)malloc((SQL_PATH_SZ + 1) * sizeof(char));

  /* Initialize cfgStruct */
  cfgStruct.numItems = 1;
  cfgStruct.paramArray = cfgParameters;
  cfgStruct.flags = db2CfgDatabase;
  cfgStruct.dbname = dbAlias;

  db2CfgGet(db2Version970, (void *)&cfgStruct, &sqlca);
  DB2_API_CHECK("log path -- get");

  strcpy(logPath, cfgParameters[0].ptrvalue + 5);
  strcat(logPath, nodeName);
  strcat(logPath, "\\SAMPLE\\NODE0000\\C0000000\\");

  free(cfgParameters[0].ptrvalue);
  cfgParameters[0].ptrvalue = NULL;

  /* connect to the database */
  rc = DbConn(dbAlias, user, pswd);
  CHECKRC(rc, "DbConn");

  /* Invoke the SQL statements to fill the database log */
  printf("\n  Invoke the following SQL statements:\n");
  printf("    ALTER TABLE emp_resume DATA CAPTURE CHANGES;\n");
  printf("    COMMIT;\n");
  printf("    INSERT INTO emp_resume\n");
  printf("      VALUES('000120', 'ascii', 'This is a new resume.');\n");
  printf("            ('000030', 'ascii', 'This is another new resume');\n");
  printf("    COMMIT;\n");
  printf("    DELETE FROM emp_resume WHERE empno = '000120';\n");
  printf("    DELETE FROM emp_resume WHERE empno = '000030';\n");
  printf("    COMMIT;\n");
  printf("    DELETE FROM emp_resume WHERE empno = '000140';\n");
  printf("    ROLLBACK;\n");
  printf("    ALTER TABLE emp_resume DATA CAPTURE NONE;\n");
  printf("    COMMIT;\n");


/*
EXEC SQL ALTER TABLE emp_resume DATA CAPTURE CHANGES;
*/

{
#line 194 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 194 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)24,1,0,0,0L);
#line 194 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 194 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 1 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL COMMIT;
*/

{
#line 197 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 197 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)21,0,0,0,0L);
#line 197 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 197 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 2 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO emp_resume
    VALUES('000120', 'ascii', 'This is a new resume.'),
    ('000030', 'ascii', 'This is another new resume');
*/

{
#line 202 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 202 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)24,2,0,0,0L);
#line 202 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 202 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 3 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL COMMIT;
*/

{
#line 205 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 205 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)21,0,0,0,0L);
#line 205 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 205 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 4 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL DELETE FROM emp_resume WHERE empno = '000120';
*/

{
#line 208 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 208 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)24,3,0,0,0L);
#line 208 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 208 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 5 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL DELETE FROM emp_resume WHERE empno = '000030';
*/

{
#line 211 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 211 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)24,4,0,0,0L);
#line 211 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 211 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 6 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL COMMIT;
*/

{
#line 214 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 214 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)21,0,0,0,0L);
#line 214 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 214 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 7 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL DELETE FROM emp_resume WHERE empno = '000140';
*/

{
#line 217 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 217 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)24,5,0,0,0L);
#line 217 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 217 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 8 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL ROLLBACK;
*/

{
#line 220 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 220 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)28,0,0,0,0L);
#line 220 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 220 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 9 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL ALTER TABLE emp_resume DATA CAPTURE NONE;
*/

{
#line 223 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 223 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)24,6,0,0,0L);
#line 223 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 223 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 10 -- invoke");


/*
EXEC SQL COMMIT;
*/

{
#line 226 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastrt(sqla_program_id, &sqla_rtinfo, &sqlca);
#line 226 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlacall((unsigned short)21,0,0,0,0L);
#line 226 "dblognoconn.sqc"
  sqlastop(0L);
}

#line 226 "dblognoconn.sqc"

  EMB_SQL_CHECK("SQL statement 11 -- invoke");

  /* Disconnect from the database */
  rc = DbDisconn(dbAlias);
  CHECKRC(rc, "DbDisconn");

  /* Detach from the local or remote instance before reading log information */
  rc = InstanceDetach(nodeName);
  CHECKRC(rc, "InstanceDetach");

  /* Invoke the db2ArchiveLog API to archive the active logs */ 
  archiveLogInput.piDatabaseAlias = dbAlias;
  archiveLogInput.piUserName = user;
  archiveLogInput.piPassword = pswd;
  archiveLogInput.iAllNodeFlag = (int)NULL;
  archiveLogInput.iNumNodes = (int)NULL;
  archiveLogInput.piNodeList = NULL;
  archiveLogInput.iOptions = (int)NULL;

  db2ArchiveLog(db2Version970, &archiveLogInput, &sqlca);
  if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
  {
     DB2_API_CHECK("database archive -- archive logs");
  }

  /* Allocate memory for the API's control blocks and log
   * buffer */ 

  readLogMemSize =  16 * 4096;

  /* Invoke the initialization API to set up the control blocks */
  readLogInit.iFilterOption = DB2READLOG_FILTER_ON;
  readLogInit.piLogFilePath = logPath;
  readLogInit.piOverflowLogPath = NULL;
  readLogInit.iRetrieveLogs = DB2READLOG_RETRIEVE_OFF;
  readLogInit.piDatabaseName = dbAlias;
  readLogInit.piDbPartitionName = nodeNum;
  readLogInit.iReadLogMemoryLimit = readLogMemSize;
  readLogInit.poReadLogMemPtr = &readLogMemory;

  db2ReadLogNoConnInit(db2Version970, &readLogInit, &sqlca);
  if (sqlca.sqlcode != SQLU_RLOG_LSNS_REUSED)
  {
     DB2_API_CHECK("database logs no db conn -- initialization");
  }

  /* Invoke the db2ReadLogNoConn API to query the current log information */
  readLogInput.iCallerAction = DB2READLOG_QUERY;
  readLogInput.piStartLSN = NULL;
  readLogInput.piEndLSN = NULL;
  readLogInput.poLogBuffer = NULL;
  readLogInput.iLogBufferSize = 0;
  readLogInput.piReadLogMemPtr = readLogMemory;
  readLogInput.poReadLogInfo = &readLogInfo;

  db2ReadLogNoConn(db2Version970, &readLogInput, &sqlca);
  if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
  {
    DB2_API_CHECK("database logs no db conn -- query");
  }

  /* Read some log records */
  logBufferSize = 64 * 1024;    /* Maximum size of a log buffer */
  logBuffer = (char *)malloc(logBufferSize);

  memcpy(&startLSN, &(readLogInfo.nextStartLSN), sizeof(startLSN));
  endLSN.lsnU64 = 0xffffffffffffffff;

  readLogInput.iCallerAction = DB2READLOG_READ;
  readLogInput.piStartLSN = &startLSN;
  readLogInput.piEndLSN = &endLSN;
  readLogInput.poLogBuffer = logBuffer;
  readLogInput.iLogBufferSize = logBufferSize;
  readLogInput.piReadLogMemPtr = readLogMemory;
  readLogInput.poReadLogInfo = &readLogInfo;

  db2ReadLogNoConn(db2Version970, &readLogInput, &sqlca);
  if (sqlca.sqlcode != SQLU_RLOG_READ_TO_CURRENT)
  {
    DB2_API_CHECK("database logs no db conn -- read");
  }
  else
  {
    if (readLogInfo.logRecsWritten == 0)
    {
      printf("\n  Database log empty.\n");
    }
  }

  /* Display the log records */
  rc = LogBufferDisplay(logBuffer, readLogInfo.logRecsWritten, 0);
  CHECKRC(rc, "LogBufferDisplay");

  while (sqlca.sqlcode != SQLU_RLOG_READ_TO_CURRENT)
  {
    /* read the next log sequence */
    memcpy(&startLSN, &(readLogInfo.nextStartLSN), sizeof(startLSN));

    /* Extract a log record and read the next log sequence asynchronously */
    db2ReadLogNoConn(db2Version970, &readLogInput, &sqlca);
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != SQLU_RLOG_READ_TO_CURRENT)
    {
      DB2_API_CHECK("database logs no db conn -- read");
    }

    /* display log buffer */
    rc = LogBufferDisplay(logBuffer, readLogInfo.logRecsWritten, 0);
    CHECKRC(rc, "LogBufferDisplay");
  }

  printf("\nRead to end of logs.\n\n");
  free(logBuffer);
  logBuffer = NULL;
  logBufferSize = 0;

  /* Invoke the db2ReadLogNoConnTerm API to terminate reading the logs */
  readLogTerm.poReadLogMemPtr = &readLogMemory;

  db2ReadLogNoConnTerm(db2Version970, &readLogTerm, &sqlca);
  DB2_API_CHECK("database logs no db conn -- terminate");

  return 0;
} /* DbReadLogRecordsNoConn */
```

I am new to Native and DB2, What is the mistake? and how to correct it?

Please excuse any errors on my part. Thanks in advance

Comment: IF your environment is *correctly set up*, then `bldapp dblognoconn` will produce an executable without errors (Windows 10 x64, Db2-LUW v11.5, Visual Studio Community-edition 2019).  The correct line to link this dblognoconn successfully is `link -debug -out:dblognoconn.exe dblognoconn.obj  utilemb.obj  db2api.lib `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the DB2 library (plus any other external libraries you call) file that contains the binary for symbols like `CmdLineArgsCheck3`.

[This](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/enterprise-developer/ed40pu6/ED-VS2015/GUID-DCAA304C-9303-4F1D-B65A-96C9B8B38233.html) suggests the DB2 library might be called `db2api.lib`.

You must either have the library file(s) in the local directory or add a linker option that points to their directory.